# Hide command line / shell when using GLUI

Tags: opengl, glut

I'm working on an openGL project and have chosen to use [GLUI](http://glui.sourceforge.net/) for my interface. Was just wondering if anyone knows how to hide the command line / shell when running?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio and C++ on Windows you can use the solution posted in the [GLUT FAQ](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/faq), [question 36](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/faq/#Q36):

> A36: Try using the following Microsoft Visual C compiler flags:
>
> `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup`
>
> These are linker options... if main or wmain are defined, MSVC build a CONSOLE app by default; hence the need for `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`. if `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is defined, MSVC expects WinMain or wWinMain to be defined; hence the need to `/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup` (eg the entry point is the usual C main).

Comment: Fantastic cheers!

If anyone else has this problem using VS:

Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - System. Change Subsystem parameter from Console to Windows.

Then Linker - Command Line - Additional Options - /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup